# Find first match to column 1 in columns 2:4 - R

Tags: r

Comparing "x1", "x2", an "x3" to "target", how do I return the *first* index of the column that matches "target"? An NA can result for no match.

```
pop <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
target <- pop
x1 <- sample(pop)
x2 <- sample(pop)
x3 <- sample(pop)
df <- data.frame(target,x1,x2,x3)

> df
  target x1 x2 x3
1      A  B  B  D
2      B  D  C  C
3      C  C  A  A
4      D  A  D  B
```

I have tried using something along the lines of:

```
min(which(df[3, 1] == df[3, 2:ncol(df)]))
```

...(row 3 being used as an example), but I don't know how to gracefully handle cases where there is no match, which is probably why I am having trouble using this in a function with apply(). The goal is either a new column on df or a vector of the returned values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `match` -

```
> df
  target x1 x2 x3
1      A  C  A  C
2      B  A  B  B
3      C  D  D  D
4      D  B  C  A

apply(df, 1, function(x) match(TRUE, x[-1] == x[1]))

[1]  2  2 NA NA
```

---

Data -

```
df <- structure(list(target = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), x1 = c("C", "A", 
"D", "B"), x2 = c("A", "B", "D", "C"), x3 = c("C", "B", "D", 
"A")), .Names = c("target", "x1", "x2", "x3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the purpose of the solution that uses _sapply()_, but the _apply()_ solution works really nicely. Thanks!

Comment: I was a bit confused about your question so provided both. Anyways editing now.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.  Loop through the columns 2:4, compare with the `target` and get the index of first match with `which`

```
sapply(df[-1], function(x) which(x == df$target)[1])
 x1 x2 x3 
#1  3 NA
```

If it is for comparing the rows

```
m1 <-  df$target == df[-1]
max.col(m1, 'first') *  NA^!rowSums(m1)
```

Or

```
apply(m1, 1, function(x) which(x)[1])
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(target,x1,x2,x3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```